# The FAQ talks about applying skeptics

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-faq

From the FAQ:

> Skeptics - Stack Exchange is for skeptics, rationalists, free thinkers anyone who questions woo and pseudoscience. **Skeptics is aimed at *applied* skeptics**; researching specific areas of woo or pseudoscience. It is not for philosophical discussions about skepticism.

[As a I pointed out on Area51 Discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/939/skeptic-exchange-proposal-updated/944#944), I doubt we can apply skeptics and Robert agreed.

Can the FAQ be fixed like the Area51 description was?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable request. Retag as "bug", not discussion?

Comment: @Oddthinking: Good point. Done.

Comment: "Woo"? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is status-completed (placeholder answer to get this question off the unanswered list).